# How to initialize UIViewController with existing UIView in .xib

Tags: ios, objective-c

Imagine a `UIViewController` that is initialized with a `.xib` file. Now imagine that this `.xib` contains a `subview` which is a `UICollectionView` object.

How would one initialize a `UICollectionViewController` instance using this `UICollectionView` instance?

I have tried:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyUICollectionViewControllerSubclass *controller = [[MyUICollectionViewControllerSubclass alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; //no matching .xib
    controller.collectionView = self.collectionView;

    [self addChildViewController:controller]; [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

But for some reason `MyUICollectionViewControllerSubclass` is never even firing `viewDidLoad` or `loadView`.

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionViewController` has:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UICollectionView *collectionView;
```

So, after you create your instance you can explicitly set the `collectionView` property to the subview (that you need to get a reference to either (preferably) from an outlet / tag / subview iteration.

Comment: This is pretty much what I have been trying. For some reason MyUICollectionViewControllerSubclass is never even firing viewDidLoad or loadView . In my parent controller I have implemented the following code:

Comment: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    MyUICollectionViewControllerSubclass *controller = [[MyUICollectionViewControllerSubclass alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    controller.collectionView = self.collectionView;

    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    
}

Comment: I wouldn't expect those methods to fire. If the view is already loaded then it won't be requested to load or notified that it did load...